# How to construct forecast confidence interval from the historical RMSE?

Tags: regression, time-series, distributions, forecasting, error

I'm reading a FED paper on forecast uncertainty estimation. Here's the [link](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://www.federalreserve.gov/econresdata/feds/2017/files/2017020pap.pdf)

One of their methods to estimate forecast interval is illustrated in the following figure

[image]

According to the description: "Uncertainty bands equal median SEP forecasts plus or minus average historical root mean squared prediction errors for each series at the appropriate forecast horizon."

I'm not sure how to derive mathematical expressions for this method. Let's say I fit a AR(1) model, from which the root mean square prediction error is calculated as:
$$RMSE = \sqrt{\frac {\sum_{t=1}^T {{\left ( y_t-\hat{y_t} \right )}^2}} {T}}$$

Do I then add and subtract the forecast estimates with some sort of "average historical" of this $RMSE$? I'm not sure what that means. Also I'm likely missing something given that the intervals tend to get larger towards the end.